# Python not finding module, even after path updated and blank __init__.py files created for subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I have installed OpenCV in a virtual enviroment (/home/jamesmcintyre/.local/pipx/venvs/opencv-python) and I have added '/home/jamesmcintyre/.local/pipx/venvs' to my sys.path as described [here](http://www.bdnyc.org/2012/09/editing-pythonpath-to-import-modules/)

I've also created an empty text file called `__init__.py` in relevant subdirectories of OpenCV-python but `import cv2` is still not working.

Can anyone please tell me why this isn't working and how I can get modules to load from non-conventional directories/sub-directories?

OS: Pop20.04 (Ubuntu compatible Linux)

Comment: The edit should not have been approved. Python posts should carry the parent python tag. Plenty of people will not see your question by dropping it. You were correct the first time :)

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to add the path manually? If the module is properly installed, activating the virtual environment will make it importable for the venv's python. Did you active the virtual environment? Do you intend to use the module with *another* python/virtual environment?

Comment: I intend to use it from a differnt enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my own question on this though I'm not sure if it's the best one or not.

Rather than updating the path, you can change your working directory before import and then switch back.

Here is the code to do this:

```
def PipxImport(ImportName,*InstallName):
import os

CL = os.getcwd()

FolderName = ImportName

i = 0    
for arg in InstallName:
    if i == 0:
        FolderName = arg
    else:
        break
    i = i + 1

if os.name == 'nt':
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~") + '\\.local\\pipx\\venvs\\' + FolderName + '\\Lib\\site-packages') 
else:
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~") + '/.local/pipx/venvs/' + FolderName + '/lib64/python3.8/site-packages') 

ImportName = __import__(ImportName)

os.chdir(CL)

return ImportName
```

I've also created a repo for it, which is more likely to be up to date than the above and also has an explanation of how to use it etc.

https://github.com/FunckyFizz/PipxImport

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code - it is a SyntaxError as such. You may also want to take a look at PEP 8, specifically idiomatic naming.